# Retrieve header of column if it has a certain value

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a csv file with headers in the following format:

`column1`,`column2`,`column3`

`True`,`False`,`False`

`False`,`True`,`True`

In python, I would like to print the column name if a value of `True` is under it (`column1` and then for the next row `column2` and `column3`). In the code I have below, it's printing every column.

```
    with open(reportOut, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, skipinitialspace=True)
        header = next(reader)
        for row in reader:
            if 'True' in row:
                print(header)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
import csv

with open("my.csv", 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, skipinitialspace=True)
    headers = next(reader)
    # Start counting from 2 (Row #1 is headers)
    for row_number, row in enumerate(reader, 2):
        for column, val in enumerate(row):  # On each column in the row
            if val == "True":  # Check for the value
                # Print the header according to the column number
                print(row_number, headers[column])
```

Output:

```
2 column1
3 column2
3 column3
```